# Login Error in ATOM Mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate

I am getting error 'Could not log in to Salesforce.com: Error: certificate not trusted' while logging in through mavensmate.I have opened ip ranges as well but issue is still there.Any guess how to resolve this?

Comment: Getting the same exception with 0.14 on mavensmate. 'Could not log in to Salesforce.com: Error: certificate not trusted'

Answer (score 2):

What version of Mavensmate are you using? There's an old issue [here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/issues/11) which points that this may be related to Ruby version. Are you trying to connect to a Sandbox or production org?

Also, there may be issues if you are updating a previous version vs. doing a fresh install. Read more [here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/issues/252).

Answer (score 0):

This could be tied down to a particular version of the request module that NodeJS is using (assumign this is the version of MM that uses the Node based API).  I had a similar issue logging into Salesforce from Heroku, and using a specific version of the request module solved the problem.

This might not be a useful answer for all end users, but if you can find the package.json for MM then the fix might be specifying a version number for request in there.

Answer (score 0):

As a note for everyone:

This issue was logged against the project for this in [github as issue #129](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Atom/issues/129) which was determined to be a problem with Atom.io itself. There is a new version of Atom (0.177) which you should upgrade to followed by upgrading MavensMate Atom to v0.15. This should resolve the issue you are having.